# Angular: Export Components from Lazy Loaded Module

Tags: angular

1. `AppModule`:

   > - has `ShellModule` as lazy load
2. `ShellModule`:

   > - import `SharableModule`
   >
   >   - **use `SharableComponent`**
   > - has `FooModule` as lazy load

`SharableModule`:

> - export `SharableComponent`
> - provide `SharableService`

3. `FooModule`:

   > - routing `FooComponent` OR `BarComponent`
4. `FooComponent`, `BarComponent`

   > - **use `ShareableComponent`**

---

Does not work `SharableModule.exports` with lazy load, So can not use `SharableComponent` in `FooModule`

> is that right?

I added Components List of `SharableModule` to `FooModule`  then work right.

but occured error, because declared on 2 modules(`ShellModule`, `FooModule`).

but `ShellModule` Components required `SharableModule` Features like `FooModule`

> have anything right way?

Answer (score 3):

It is addressed quite comprehensively at the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq).

Generally, you should have **`shared.module`** where you can import/export all your shareable component/directive, other modules. And it will be import in any *lazy-loading modules* you want to use it.

For `services`, generally they should be singleton (single instance) for your whole application to use. Therefore, they should be grouped in so-called **`core.module`** and this module will be imported in your `root.module` (aka. app.module`).

Any **feature modules** should be lazy-loading modules.

The project structure is something like this:

```
+--app
    |
    +--core.module/
    |   |
    |   +--(import your sevices here...)
    |
    +--shared.module
    |   |
    |   +--(import/export all your components/directives/modules here)
    |
    +--any-lazy-loading.module
    |   |
    |   +--(import shared-module here)
    |
    app.module
        |
        +--(import core.module here)
```

Comment: thanks, i wanted the better way of this case like `provideIn`, but seems to impossible. did you made tree yourself or used any tool?

Comment: That simple tree can be created with any editor. Can you specify `provideIn`?

Comment: if has some ascii tree auto-generator, i wanted know it. 
sorry, it was `providedIn`. i just wanted component declaration like not-lazy loading that has not additional code , or wish to work it. at least as like `providedIn`

Comment: Its a little bit off topic, but if you are using linux, then just `sudo apt-get install tree` then you can print to console the current folder tree as `tree`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use SharableModule to provide SharableService as each lazy loaded module that imports the service will end up with different instance of the service. If you need to use all those services as singleton then add them to core module. You can also create a separate core-service.module. Use Sharable Module to just share components or directives.

You can do this

```
core-components.module.ts[ Add core components]
core-services.module.ts[ Add all shared services]
shared.module.ts [ this module exports all shared component and modules]
```

In the shell.module.ts import the SharedModule i.e. shared.module
In the foo.module import the SharedModule i.e shared.module
Similarly you can add as many modules[ lazy loaded or non lazy loaded] with just SharedModule imported as the common module.

This will prevent any cyclic dependencies and let you share the common components across the app modules.